# How to avoid conflict between JQuery and Prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, conflict

If a page has both JQuery and Prototype then I got conflict. There is a option to disable $ sign for JQuery so there is no conflict but, I have to use keyword JQuery instead of $.

I wonder if there is any option for Prototype to solve this conflict. Is there any way to use both libraries without compromising their benefit or short keyword?

As far as I know, it is not a good idea to use multiple JS library for same page; but it may be helpful for sometimes.

Comment: make sure you load jQuery before prototype

Comment: I'm thinking that this has to be one of the most asked jQuery questions :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the [noConflict](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict) method for jQuery and assign it to a new (short) variable.  Use the new variable wherever you would have used the $ for jQuery.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function() {
    $j('#selector').each( .... );
});
```

or, if you don't need to mix Prototype/jQuery you can wrap all of your jQuery code in an anonymous function.

```
(function($) {
    // $ sign here is a parameter, which is set to jQuery 

    $(function() {
        $('#selector').each( .... );
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Is there any particular order that jQuery has to be included (first, last, etc) for either of your code examples?

Comment: If you use noConflict, jQuery has to be included before you call it (obviously) as does the other library defining the $.  See this page for more info: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Comment: @tvanfosson  
I didn't knew that a variable can be assigned, nice trick :) Uhh... I know about the second technique, but dont like it :( it makes me confuse easily. Thank you for your time :)