# Jquery and Prototype Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, conflict

I am having trouble running two javascript files on the same page. I used JQuery.noConflict() (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) but no luck.

```
        <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script>
            google.load("prototype", "1.6.0.3",{uncompressed:false});
            google.load("scriptaculous", "1.8.1",{uncompressed:false});
        </script>
        <script src="js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $jQuery.noConflict();
          jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $("#download_now").tooltip({ effect: 'slide'});
          });

            function show_text() {
            new Ajax.Request('./new.php', {
                             method: 'post',
                             parameters: { userid: $('userid').value },
                             onSuccess: function(r) { $('update').update(r.responseText) }
                                 });    
            }

            document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {

            $('loading').hide();

            Ajax.Responders.register({
              onCreate: function() {
                new Effect.Opacity('loading',{ from: 1.0, to: 0.3, duration: 0.7 });        
                new Effect.toggle('loading', 'appear');


              },
              onComplete: function() {
                new Effect.Opacity('loading', { from: 0.3, to: 1, duration: 0.7 });
                new Effect.toggle('loading', 'appear');
              }
            });
            });         
            </script>
```

Comment: I find it amusing you had to add the PHP tag when this has nothing to do with PHP...

Comment: Read my answer here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871430/make-prototype-and-tokeninput-js-files-work-together/21955328#21955328
I did it and it worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe  `$jQuery.noConflict();` in your code is a typo. Use `jQuery.noConflict();`.

Another method to solve your problem is by replacing all `$` variables with jQuery (provided that `$` is referrring to a jQuery object).

Answer (score 4):

Read this:

> - [How to avoid conflict between JQuery and Prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401349/how-to-avoid-conflict-between-jquery-and-prototype)

or just search stackoverflow like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+conflict-prototype

Answer (score 2):

load jQuery first and then call this code:

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
//Now you can use $jq in place of $ for jQuery;
$jq(".myButton").css("border","2px");
```

Load other libraries.