# Code stops working when I try to modify the DOM in jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I am trying to modify DOM elements but for some reason the code gets jammed up.

```
 var length = tabOne.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(tabOne[i] == sPage){ 
            alert("In Tab One");

            // Set the top nav link as current (Get the first link in #nav-main)
            $("#nav-main a:first").addClass("current");         
            // Set the sub nav link as current (Find it by URL)
            $("a[href='" + sPage + "']").addClass("current");
            // Show the sub nav
            $("#nav-sub-welcome").css('display', '');

            alert("We got this far");
        }
    }
```

The script never displays the alert at the end. I tried commenting out specific manipulations but for some reason the alert wont run unless they are all commented out. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Does it display anything on the console window? Any error/exception being thrown?

Comment: And what happens if you only comment second one?

Comment: I'm looking in the error console now. It is pulling up errors for each one. All of them are telling me that the thing I am trying to call is undefined.

Comment: Are you sure JQuery is being loaded? Try $(document).ready(function(){ alert('it works!'); });

Comment: It seems like jQuery is not loaded. Once you get this worked out, remove .css('display', '') and use .show() instead.

Comment: Looks like there may be some conflict. It is telling me that document ready is not a function. I am trying to find a way to work around the conflict now by searching Google but if you guys have a good alternative please post an answer. ty.

Comment: It is conflicting with prototype

Comment: This has been fixed, thank you guys for helping me hone in on it

Comment: Please remember to post the solution below and accept it.

Comment: For the future, it would be good to provide information in your question about other frameworks or libraries in use on the same page. I suspected you might have a conflict, but you didn't mention any other libs and I thought it was too simple an answer... lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the page this code was being used on was also loading prototype, and they conflicted. [Read this to learn how to avoid conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401349/how-to-avoid-conflict-between-jquery-and-prototype).