# Including jquery in a separate php header file somehow fails

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a website, and have been working with some jQuery scripting that didnt seem to work. But after some time, I discovered that I had to link to the jQuery lib in my content file.

My hierachy is as follows:

- header.php (common header html)
- link/index.php ( where "link" is any subfolder on the domain, i.e: contact/index.php, home/index.php etc )
- footer.php

All of these content files uses a "require_once("header.php")" and the same for the footer, templating technique.

Even though viewing the source in a browser links succsessfully to the included scripts and CSS files, it doesent seem to load jQuery (only). But when I included it in the specific content file, the script I wrote worked.

Here is some of the relevant code:

*in header.php:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="NO">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>

<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script> 
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/shl_menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/lightbox.js"></script>
```

*In gallery/index.php (content file)*

```
<?php require_once("../header.php"); ?>

<!-- Sub Menu List -->
<nav id="shl-submenu" class="left shadow-box rounded-corners">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) 
{
    $("#shl-submenu ul li a").click(function(e) {
        alert("Click");
    });
});
 ...
```

Now, if I include  `<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>` above that script, it works, but not unless.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: So when the page renders, does the browser load jquery-latest.pack.js or does it say 404?

Comment: Without knowing how your directory structure is laid out, it might because of the relative URLs not pointing to the correct location.

Comment: That is just it. It should be loaded, since when I click the script href (in google chrome's "view page source") it links correctly and I also downloaded the lib, and linked locally to make sure. Does not work unless I include it in the content file alone (which uses the same link as in header.php )

Comment: I just removed the prototype.js script tag. That fixed it. BUT, why do they conflict?

Comment: I could not answer my own question yet, but it seems like jQuery must be included AFTER prototype.js.

Comment: Dealing with conflicts between jQuery and Prototype, see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401349/how-to-avoid-conflict-between-jquery-and-prototype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you guessed there is a conflict between jQuery and Prototype.  Both define the $ as a function.  You can always use the variable `jQuery` instead of `$` to avoid this and declare prototype after jQuery.  This post explains a good way to handle this:

[How to avoid conflict between JQuery and Prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401349/how-to-avoid-conflict-between-jquery-and-prototype)

Comment: Ok, so thats what the conflict is :) Thank you for clarifying!