# Conflict between JQuery and Prototype.js

Tags: ajax, jquery, prototypejs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid conflict between JQuery and Prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401349/how-to-avoid-conflict-between-jquery-and-prototype)

I am adding an enhancement to my company's software. I am using JQuery for Ajax Request calls. But my company uses Prototype.js for the same. Now, when I integrate my enhancement to the main software, I am getting conflicts between Prototype.js and JQuery as both use "$" symbols.

Can anyone help me with this?

I have to include both, JQuery and Prototype.js at the same time and really cannot avoid anyone of those.

Comment: i tried doing that.. Did not work!!

Comment: Should have googled your title `Conflict between JQuery and Prototype.js`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put your jQuery codes within:

```
(function($){
     $(document).ready(function(){

     })
})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to prevent it from registering itself as the `$` variable. Then wrap your jQuery calls using these patterns:

```
(function($)
{
    $(''); // jQuery object.
})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $(''); // jQuery object.
});
```