# Arrangement of javascripts in header file affecting functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a site where I use some jquery functionalities.
On the home page I used Nivo Slider plugin, while on another page I used a Lightbox effect.

In the arrangement of links to the script in my `header.php` file, I have the lightbox link under Nivo Slider link. Lightbox works but Nivo slider does not work. When I re-arrange, slider works but lightbox does not work.

**In this situation LightBox works, but slider does not work**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>

<script src="js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>      
<script src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is this normal? How can I make both work at the same time.

My Homepage that has the slider is [Here](http://goo.gl/QgxUl)

Page that has lightbox is [here](http://goo.gl/sIJOz)

Thank you.

Comment: Look into [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict).

Comment: a side note - also look into not making your page call 30 different script files

Comment: @ScottSelby what if i need all the files ? Can I combine them into 1 ?

Comment: @ScottSelby My understanding of JS is a bit crude, so forgive me if my questions seems absurd.

Comment: @icktoofay I have only downloaded and implemented scripts I found useful online, i did not write them.

Comment: @user1843335: Yes, but all of the scripts you've downloaded conflict and won't work with eachother without configuring them (and possibly modifying them) to not conflict. You cannot expect shoving a bunch of unrelated things into your web page to work without knowing how they interact.

Comment: @icktoofay Okay. Thanks for pointing that out to me. How do I start ?

Comment: @user1843335  - icktoofay is right , and you absolutely can and should put them in one file , ideally over time you can learn to write just what you need on your own all in one file , but for now you have to find out what the conflicts are and browser debugger will help out a lot with that

Comment: @icktoofay Thanks for the process you have highlighted, I have done exactly what you said, but I still cant get the slider to work.

Comment: @icktoofay Everywhere i see `$` should be replaced with `jQuery` ?

Comment: @user1843335: Almost. Wherever it's referring to jQuery. Most of your code uses jQuery, so you'll want to replace most of them, but at least one is part of a regular expression where you won't want to replace it. (`/^[0-9]+(\.([0-9]+))?$/`)

Comment: @icktoofay I guess i will do the replacements in jQuery scripts, and leave Prototype and Scriptalicious script.

Thanks a lot

Comment: @icktoofay i replaced `$` with `jQuery` but still not working.
Thanks

Comment: @icktoofay I see it and have replaced them all. Still same error.

Comment: @user1843335: It seems to somewhat work for me (although some parts are still a little broken), but I just remembered that Prototype does more extensive changes that are harder to work around. I'm not really sure what to do about that, other than trying to find a different lightbox thing that doesn't use Prototype.

Comment: @icktoofay Can you please give a proper answer.

Comment: @icktoofay It works now. Also what resources to recommend I read ? Thanks a million.

Comment: @user1843335: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1401349) may be a good read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With lots of code from lots of places, some things stop working. One can not simply assume that adding little bits of code that individually work will work when integrated together. In this particular case, jQuery and Prototype are fighting.

This can be fixed by loading only one jQuery at the top, and then including this little snippet:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Then jQuery no longer takes over the `$` variable. (Your code will also need to account for this change by using `jQuery` rather than `$`, but all well-written plugins should interoperate decently with this change.)

After that, you should be able to include Prototype and your other plugins. In theory, anyways.

---

In practice, Prototype hooks some other things. In your particular case, it's hooking `Array.​prototype.​reverse` in a way that the jQuery plugins don't expect, and somehow, it's causing a stack overflow. I don't really know how to resolve Prototype's hijacking of that function without breaking one or the other, so you might just want to find a lightbox plugin that works with just jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not available when you are trying to call it. You could try moving everything to the bottom of the body. Also worth noting that you are loading jQuery twice.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did what you said, but it's not working still. Please what do I do next ?